# how to add zeroes to the right of a number in python?

Tags: python

yesterday I saw someone in Youtube adding zeroes to a number by just adding a letter next to the number then how many zeroes he wants to add.

I was something like this " 5(a letter)3
the it will print : 5000

Can someone tell me how again please. Thank you so much

Note: it's not zfill or "%0.3f"

Comment: `5e3` is scientific notation for 5000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `e`

```
>>>5e3
5000.0
```